# Join condition reading form YAML file coming as String

Tags: python, yaml

In my project I want to maintain join conditions (pyspark dataframe join conditions) in `YAML` file.

Sample join condition looks like this.

`table1.col1 ==  table2.col1`

In YAML, conditions are like this.

`cond: table1.col1 ==  table2.col1`

When I reading the join condition from YAML. I am getting as below(of type String).

```
table1.col1 ==  table2.col1
```

The condition is converted as String(enclosed in single quotes).

To solve this(for getting exact literal instead of string), I tried below approaches. But, they are not working.

1)

```
import ast
final_cond = ast.literal_eval(cond)
```

2)

```
import json
final_cond = json.loads(cond)
```

I need the exact literal while reading instead of String or convert such kind of equality join condition from String to literal.

Note: To apply join conditions, one way is to write code like this.

```
joined = table1.join(table2, [table1.col1 == table2.col1], "inner")
```

But, If I take the condition from YAML, `joined` becomes as below.

```
joined = table1.join(table2, ['table1.col1 == table2.col1'], "inner")  # notice the enclosed single quotes
```

The quotes(single or double) are the reason for failure.

Currently, YAML file has only below pair. I will add further similar conditions if this approach works out.

```
cond: table1.col1 ==  table2.col1
```

Comment: What did you expect to get? YAML is just strings. Also a sample of the YAML-file could be helpful

Comment: I updated  the question with further explanation of problem.

Comment: A YAML file is a string. Everything you read are strings. It has no concept of types or 'condition'. You will need to do a conversion. Some form of an evaluation which exists in some languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YAML, `table1.col1 ==  table2.col1` is a scalar. A scalar is a sequence of characters that is by default loaded into a string.

In Python, `table1.col1 ==  table2.col2` is an expression that is parsed into a part of the AST. In the standard implementation, the AST is processed into bytecode and put into `.pyc` files. This all happens before any code is executed, which means it happens before the code reads your YAML file. This is why you can't directly inject parts of the AST from YAML.

However, you have access to Python's parsing and interpreting facilities at runtime (this is, simply put, what distinguishes today's so-called „interpreted“ languages from the compiled ones). This means that you can write

```
joined = table1.join(table2, [eval('table1.col1 == table2.col1')], "inner")
```

`eval()` parses the given string as Python source and then evaluates it in the current context (i.e. resolving all names to locals visible at the call site). This way, you can evaluate the string you got from your YAML file as if it was part of your Python source code.

Beware that `eval()` is basically as powerful as the Python language as a whole, so before you use it, make sure that it never gets executed on any string you do not have complete control over. If you ever execute `eval()` on input from a user, the user can basically execute any code within your application, which is a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks @flyx. This is exactly what I am looking for. It's working as expected.